# Auto Login to a WEB Browser from c# WPF code

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I am trying to login to the site https://kite.zerodha.com/ from a Webbrowser control in my C# WPF application. I am stuck because of the way the source code of the site is written as for none of the Input / Action elements there is any ID/TAG/NAME by which I can get the element and pass my input from my program.

The source code of the site for the password field looks something like below :

```
<input type="password" maxlength="30" placeholder="" autocorrect="off" animate="true" label="" rules="[object Object]" dynamicwidthsize="8" autocomplete="off">
```

In my C# code on `Loadcompletion` of the browser I have got the HTML document as below:

```
htmldoc = LogInBrowser.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
```

But now I am not able to proceed as to how can I access the password field and pass my input from my program.

Some guidance would be of great help!

Thanks,
Nandy

Comment: Request the C# masters to provide some guidance on my above question. Thanks Nandy

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by small trick. Pass your password in the `OuterHtml` of HTML element. Add the value element in the `OuterHtml` value=\"Your_Password\"

```
// Get password element
HtmlElement passwordElement = (from HtmlElement element in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input") select element)
    .Where(x => x.GetAttribute("type") == "password").FirstOrDefault();

if (passwordElement != null)
{
    passwordElement.OuterHtml = "<input type=\"password\" maxlength=\"30\" placeholder=\"Password\" autocorrect=\"off\" animate=\"true\" label=\"\" rules=\"[object Object]\" dynamicWidthSize=\"8\" autocomplete=\"off\" value=\"Your_Password\">";
}
```